# Please explain the grammatical structure of the bold part in the sentence

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> Spotify’s initial foray into Asia saw it land in small and fairly
>   Western-influenced countries like Hong Kong and Singapore, **markets
>   where it was likely to see uptake**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Markets* is an appositive, renaming "Hong Kong and Singapore".  *Where* is a subordinate conjunction linking its reference (*markets*) to the descriptive clause "it was likely to see uptake".  The antecedent of *it* is Spotify.

It means that Spotify started its Asian business in places that where it would probably be successful because those places were commercially  Westernized.

Comment: I appreciate your close explanation. Grammatical terms like appositive, subordinate conjunction ... are very helpful in understanding the structure of the sentence.

Comment: So are you saying that "where" is a **relative adverb** and _where it was likely to see uptake_ is a **relative clause**?

Comment: Yes.  *it* (subject) *was* (verb) *likely* (predicate adjective) *to see uptake* (adjectival complement, in which *to see* is an infinitive with object *uptake*).  *Where* connects its referent *markets* to the suborindate clause.  We can ponder at what point in that clause.  I don't regard the appositive as a modifier but as a replacement name.  You can leave *markets* out, and the subordinate clause refers to the compound object of the preposition *like*, i.e, "Hong Kong and Singapore".

Comment: @deadrat. "Where" takes locative expressions as antecedent; within the relative clause it functions as an adjunct of spatial location, typically represented by a preposition phrase. So we understand _it was likely to see uptake **in those markets**_. Whether there is actually an appositive here seems debateable, though it might be possible to make a case for “markets …” being a supplementary appositive whose anchor is the larger NP _small and fairly western-influenced countries like Hong Kong and Singapore_. Supplementary appositives aren’t modifiers, so that would seem plausible.